# Why won't my .html file connect to .js file?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, debugging

I want to connect my `.html` to `.js`.  I'm trying to run this simple program but it's not working.   Below is the screenshot of my file path and files I'm working with.

[image]

Here's `map.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>

</body>
<script type="javascript" src="map.js"></script>
</html>
```

Here's `map.js`:

```
document.write("testing");
```

The problem is below.  How can I render the `.js` file along with the `.html` file?

Here's `views.py`:

```
def map(request):
    return render(request, 'personal/map.html')
```

Comment: remove the type attribute... modern browsers will not run javascript if it doesnt use the proper mime type for javascript

Comment: @PatrickEvans I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Open your browser console, do you see any errors in there?

Comment: If it's straight html and your url to access maps.html is <something>/personal/templates/personal/maps.html then it should work.  I'm guessing whatever templating system you're using is crunching the url to something else, and maps.js is not found in the same relative place.

Comment: @James Posted `views.py` file in my original post.

Comment: Is your Python file properly indented? Before I fixed the indentation, it was not.

Comment: @DYZ Yeah it is.  I forgot to fix it when I posted it.

Comment: you can and only can download css、js、img through `/static/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common CMS convention is to save JavaScript files in a static folder. 
You save anything that you don't want your template engine messing with there: images, javascript, css, etc.

It looks like you may need to save `map.js` at this path:

```
mysite/personal/static/personal/js/map.js
```

After that, you'll need to update you script link in your HTML to something like:

```
<script src="static/js/map.js">
```

The `src` path here isn't relative to where you store the file on your computer, but to the URI that your web server associates with it. 
Depending on how you've set things up, you'll need some portion of the new path.
Django has [a few ways of linking to static resources](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/), but I'm not familiar enough with the platform to tell you which option you should use.

Comment: It's actually `<script src="../../static/personal/js/map.js"></script>` and not `<script src="static/js/map.js">`.  I used yours as guidance and it worked!  Thanks a lot man :D.